# My android app keeps crashing when I launch it

Tags: android

I recently got some app source code. So I imported to Eclipse and renamed application package. It all went well until I tried launch the app. When I do it instantly crashes. I was wondering why.  This is the log:

```
E/ActivityManager(  215): heap conf. property name string trimmed: hs.com.shadycorp.MoonStoneMarbl
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.shadycorp.MoonStoneMarble/theHardestGame.pac.GameLogicController}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: theHardestGame.pac.GameLogicController in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.shadycorp.MoonStoneMarble-1.apk]
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1580)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1674)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:942)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: theHardestGame.pac.GameLogicController in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.shadycorp.MoonStoneMarble-1.apk]
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1572)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): [Blue Error Handler] Make Debugging Report file for main
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.shadycorp.MoonStoneMarble/theHardestGame.pac.GameLogicController}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: theHardestGame.pac.GameLogicController in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.shadycorp.MoonStoneMarble-1.apk]
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1580)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1674)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:942)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: theHardestGame.pac.GameLogicController in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.shadycorp.MoonStoneMarble-1.apk]
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5644): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1572)
```

this is my android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="theHardestGame.pac"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".GameLogicController"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Your activity is not instantiated. can u update the logs with sidebars.

Comment: this class `theHardestGame.pac.GameLogicController` was not found. Check your imports, classnames, and manifest.

Comment: Does `GameLogicController` extend `Activity`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the default action in AndroidManifest.xml. It's probably set to theHardestGame.pac.GameLogicController and should be something else.

Comment: ok i put my android manifest up so what should i try and also could sombidy examine my code if i email

Comment: What is the name of the Activity that you want to start with? Replace ".GameLogicController" with that one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've not updated the package consistently. In your manifest it's "theHardestGame.pac", while the application package seems to be "com.shadycorp.MoonStoneMarble". I suggest you search for those strings and make sure you've updated everything. Also make sure you're doing a clean build.